# Find periodicity of a function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{2+\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, periodic-functions

$$\exists p\neq 0 : x\in D (f(x+p)=f(x))$$
where $D$ is the domain of $f(x)$.

$$f(x+p)=\frac{\sin (x+p)}{2+\cos (x+p)}=\frac{\sin p\cos x+\sin x\cos p}{2+\cos p\cos x-\sin x\sin p}$$

$$\frac{\sin x}{2+\cos x}=\frac{\sin p\cos x+\sin x\cos p}{2+\cos p\cos x-\sin x\sin p} /(2+\cos x)(2+\cos p\cos x-\sin x\sin p)$$

$$\sin x(2+\cos p\cos x-\sin x\sin p)=(\sin p\cos x+\sin x\cos p)(2+\cos x)$$

How to reduce this equation to find $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's set a equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin x}{2+\cos x} = \frac{\sin (x+p)}{2+\cos(x+p)}.
\end{equation}
It can be manipulated as
\begin{equation}
2\sin x +\sin x \cos (x+p) = 2\sin(x+p)+\cos x \sin(x+p).
\end{equation}
By trigonometric identities,
\begin{equation}
\sin(x+p)-\sin x =2\cos\left(x+\frac{p}{2}\right)\sin\frac{p}{2},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sin(x+p)\cos x -\sin x \cos(x+p) =\sin(x+p-x)=\sin p,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sin p =2\sin\frac{p}{2}\cos\frac{p}{2}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, a equation reduces to
\begin{equation}
4\cos\left(x+\frac{p}{2}\right)\sin\frac{p}{2}+2\sin \frac{p}{2}\cos\frac{p}{2}=0,
\end{equation}
as same as
\begin{equation}
\sin\frac{p}{2}\left(2\cos\left(x+\frac{p}{2}\right)+\cos\frac{p}{2}\right)=0.
\end{equation}
This equation must be true for all $x$. Let $x=-\frac{p}{2}$, then it reduces to
\begin{equation}
\sin\frac{p}{2}=0
\end{equation}
and solution is $p=\pm 2\pi, \pm 4\pi,\dots$ Therefore period of $f(x)$ is $2\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

The given function obviously has period $2\pi$, but there could be a smaller period, which then has to be a natural fraction of $2\pi$. As $f(x)=0$ exactly when $x\in \pi{\mathbb Z}$ we only have to test whether $\pi$ is a period. Since $f\bigl(-{\pi\over2}\bigr)=-1\ne1=f\bigl({\pi\over2}\bigr)$ this is not the case.